# htaccess url destroyed results

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to fix some strange or destroyed results with my web url, if I add any char after index.php/:

```
http://domain/index.php/?
```

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This web server feature is called **Path Info**. Look for Apaches *AcceptPathInfo* settings. What's exactly your problem? Do you want to use ordinary query strings together with path info URLs?

Comment: I don't want to use any query, just secure my url on htaccess.